# Get response from rest api

Tags: azure, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a parquet file with three columns col1,col2,col3 ,in this col3 has end key value for my api.
So
1.I want to read this parquet file from adls location and pass the end keys as one by one to my api       request.
2.Here is the most wanted thing is the response whatever it is must be store as fourth column as col4.

I tried with synapse notebook but the response I am getting null only even though there is a data in response

I tried with activities like
lookup-->forEach(copy)
here I got two issues

1. I didn't get how to add the response as fourth column
2. the response from the rest api I am getting as each row as one column

I tried with data flow also but the external_call is not supporting selfhosted IR.

Please any help is regarding this will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Here is the most wanted thing is the response whatever it is must be store as fourth column as col4' - to which location you want store this? to the file in ADLS? or to the REST API? Can you provide sample input and expected output?